# How would I send files to Raspberry Pi through bluetooth without touching the Pi?

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, headless, data-transfer, bluez

I want to be able to send code files to my `Raspberry Pi Zero W` from my Mac or Android phone, without needing to go do anything on the Pi itself.

I was able to pair and connect to my devices with `bluetoothctl`, but the problem seems to be that my devices don't recognize the Pi as a device that can receive files via Bluetooth. My headless Raspi is running a `Raspberry Pi OS Lite` and I access it (for now) by `ssh`ing to it via USB cable.

Please let me know in the comments section down below what other information you want me to provide.

Comment: Have you tried to make a Bluetooth PAN connection with the pi? Once you do that, you'll have a simplified interface to transferring files between your pi and Mac.

Comment: No, I haven't. Is it possible to also use this trick on a phone (either Android or iOS)? Because my final goal is to create an app that occasionally talks and sends files to the Pi via bluetooth.

Comment: Well if you have wifi - you could run a Flask server on the pi and have it run on localhost as a background daemon. Then you build your app to make specific url requests to the Flask server, using its routing capabilities. . . There's so much existing web infrastructure to build off of (Flask in this example), that I would navigate away from BT and embrace the powerful tools that are available for web/networking.

Comment: The app I'm creating is a companion for a custom device that has the Raspberry Pi in it. How would I connect the Raspi to the router for the first time if I want the end-user to not interact with Raspi at all and only interact with the companion app on his/her mobile phone? I'm asking this because I assume in order for Flask to work correctly, Raspi needs to be connected to the router of the end-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth is interoperable by having common ways to interact defined by the Bluetooth SIG. There is a list of these profiles at:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/

The list of profiles supported by BlueZ (the official Bluetooth stack on Linux) is documented at: http://www.bluez.org/profiles/

I suspect from your question, one of the two following profiles are most likely to do what you want:

- OPP  Object Push Profile
- PAN  Personal Area Networking Profile

There first one is probably most likely to be helpful. Often referred to as [OBEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange)

The daemon doesn't seem to be installed by default so you would need to install it with:

```
sudo apt install bluez-obexd
```

And you will have to start it. You can get the full options with:

```
/usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd -h
```

I used the following for my test:

```
/usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd -- --root=/tmp/bluetooth-inbox -l -d
```

If you do bluetoothctl show there should be an extra UUID added e.g:

```
UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

There is a command line client called `obexctl` that might be useful to help explore the functionality.

The BlueZ API for this functionality is documented at the following depending if you want a server or client:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/obex-agent-api.txt
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/obex-api.txt

If you wanted to use personal area network profile, then that API is documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/network-api.txt

As a footnote, when using `Raspberry Pi OS lite` it has been found that user pi is not necessarily a member of the bluetooth group. This can be cured as follows:

```
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

Adding `pi` to this group means that your Bluetooth program doesn't need to be run as root.

Comment: I am trying to follow your solution but when I enter `/usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd -- --root=/tmp/bluetooth-inbox -l -d` at the terminal, I get this back: `Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`. I've did a little bit of Googling but I couldn't find an appropriate solution. Would mark this as a solution if it works out!

Comment: Did you run that command as root or with sudo? There used to be a problem starting DBus services on older versions of the RPi Lite OS but I thought that had been resolved. I don't have a Pi setup with lite to test. Maybe try it with a full OS and see if works there. If it does, then see what is missing from the Lite version for your needs.

Comment: Yes, that didn't work with sudo as well

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Pi Bluetooth stack only supports HID & audio so this is not possible.

There are many protocols which allow file transfer over an IP connection.

I normally use `ftp` - which works out of the box.

I also use `Samba` (and have used `afp` and `nfs`) but these all require setting up shares on the Pi.

You can use `scp` to copy files over `ssh`.

You will find documentation on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/

Comment: Thanks! My final goal is to create an app that occasionally talks and sends files to the Pi. Can you walk me through the other methods (other than Bluetooth) I can use for staying connected to the Pi and send files to it from time to time?